# DRM session error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: {}: BAD_VALUE

Tags: android, kotlin, video, exoplayer, drm

This problem occurs when trying to play content on devices with Android 13, playback works correctly on devices with Android version 12, 8, 9

**ExoPlayer version**
2.18.2

**Devices affected**
Google Pixel 6

I attach the records obtained in AndroidStudio

Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: {}: BAD_VALUE
  cdm err: 0, oem err: 0, ctx: 0
  ============================== Beginning of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
    02-29 12:44:50.237 I [(0):] Level3 Library 28613 May  1 2023 06:32:58
    02-29 12:44:50.237 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(837):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"L3_28613","soc_model":"ARM 64 bit","ta_ver":"18.1.0+May  1 2023_06:32:58_","uses_opk":false,"tee_os":"none","tee_os_ver":"0.0.0","form_factor":"L3","implementer":"Widevine","fused":false}
    02-29 12:44:50.239 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(851):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
    02-29 12:44:50.249 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1013):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
    02-29 12:44:50.249 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1021):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc06.
    02-29 12:44:50.249 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1039):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
    02-29 12:44:50.251 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:50.251 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(885):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"GOOGLE","soc_model":"GS101","ta_ver":"18.1.0+Sep 18 202304:20:14","uses_opk":true,"tee_os":"TRUSTY","tee_os_ver":"0_0","form_factor":"PHONE+TABLET","implementer":"WIDEVINE","fused":true}
    02-29 12:44:50.253 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.750 I [cdm_usage_table.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
    02-29 12:44:51.763 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.773 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.774 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.774 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.776 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.776 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.778 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1032):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid54
    02-29 12:44:51.778 I [cdm_engine.cpp(216):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid54
    02-29 12:44:51.779 I [cdm_engine.cpp(937):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid54
    02-29 12:44:51.784 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.784 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 12:44:51.784 I [cdm_engine.cpp(303):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid54, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
    02-29 12:44:51.843 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1043):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
    02-29 12:44:51.846 I [cdm_engine.cpp(937):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid54
    02-29 12:44:52.044 I [cdm_engine.cpp(382):AddKey] session_id = sid54, key_set_id = <empty>
    02-29 12:44:52.307 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1043):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
    02-29 12:44:55.988 I [cdm_engine.cpp(261):CloseSession] session_id = sid54
    02-29 12:44:55.996 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(897):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
    02-29 12:44:55.996 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
    02-29 13:41:00.861 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(837):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"L3_28613","soc_model":"ARM 64 bit","ta_ver":"18.1.0+May  1 2023_06:32:58_","uses_opk":false,"tee_os":"none","tee_os_ver":"0.0.0","form_factor":"L3","implementer":"Widevine","fused":false}
    02-29 13:41:00.861 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 13:41:00.861 I [(0):] Level3 Library 28613 May  1 2023 06:32:58
    02-29 13:41:00.868 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(851):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
    02-29 13:41:00.880 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1021):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc06.
    02-29 13:41:00.880 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1039):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
    02-29 13:41:00.880 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1013):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
    02-29 13:41:00.887 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(885):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"GOOGLE","soc_model":"GS101","ta_ver":"18.1.0+Sep 18 202304:20:14","uses_opk":true,"tee_os":"TRUSTY","tee_os_ver":"0_0","form_factor":"PHONE+TABLET","implementer":"WIDEVINE","fused":true}
    02-29 13:41:00.889 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 13:41:00.890 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 13:41:00.896 I [cdm_usage_table.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
    02-29 13:41:00.903 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 13:41:00.906 E [wv_content_decryption_module.cpp(556):GetCurrentMetricsInternal] Cdm Identifier not found
    02-29 13:41:00.909 E [wv_content_decryption_module.cpp(639):CloseCdm] Cdm Identifier not found
    02-29 13:41:00.913 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
    02-29 13:41:00.913 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(897):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
    02-29 14:33:36.623 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(837):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"L3_28613","soc_model":"ARM 64 bit","ta_ver":"18.1.0+May  1 2023_06:32:58_","uses_opk":false,"tee_os":"none","tee_os_ver":"0.0.0","form_factor":"L3","implementer":"Widevine","fused":false}
    02-29 14:33:36.623 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:33:36.624 I [(0):] Level3 Library 28613 May  1 2023 06:32:58
    02-29 14:33:36.632 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(851):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
    02-29 14:33:36.641 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1013):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
    02-29 14:33:36.641 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1021):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc06.
    02-29 14:33:36.642 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1039):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
    02-29 14:33:36.645 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(885):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"GOOGLE","soc_model":"GS101","ta_ver":"18.1.0+Sep 18 202304:20:14","uses_opk":true,"tee_os":"TRUSTY","tee_os_ver":"0_0","form_factor":"PHONE+TABLET","implementer":"WIDEVINE","fused":true}
    02-29 14:33:36.648 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:33:36.648 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:33:36.656 I [cdm_usage_table.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
    02-29 14:33:36.662 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:33:36.664 E [wv_content_decryption_module.cpp(556):GetCurrentMetricsInternal] Cdm Identifier not found
    02-29 14:33:36.668 E [wv_content_decryption_module.cpp(639):CloseCdm] Cdm Identifier not found
    02-29 14:33:36.677 I [(0):] L3 Terminate.
    02-29 14:33:36.677 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(897):Level1Terminate] L1 Terminate
    02-29 14:46:14.436 I No hidl drm factories found
    02-29 14:46:14.437 E Failed to find passthrough drm factories
    02-29 14:46:14.441 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:14.441 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(837):Initialize] Level 3 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"L3_28613","soc_model":"ARM 64 bit","ta_ver":"18.1.0+May  1 2023_06:32:58_","uses_opk":false,"tee_os":"none","tee_os_ver":"0.0.0","form_factor":"L3","implementer":"Widevine","fused":false}
    02-29 14:46:14.442 I [(0):] Level3 Library 28613 May  1 2023 06:32:58
    02-29 14:46:14.443 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(851):Initialize] L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
    02-29 14:46:14.458 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1013):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc90.
    02-29 14:46:14.458 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1021):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc06.
    02-29 14:46:14.458 W [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(1039):LoadLevel1] Could not load L1 _oecc23.
    02-29 14:46:14.464 I [oemcrypto_adapter_dynamic.cpp(885):Initialize] Level 1 Build Info (v18): {"soc_vendor":"GOOGLE","soc_model":"GS101","ta_ver":"18.1.0+Sep 18 202304:20:14","uses_opk":true,"tee_os":"TRUSTY","tee_os_ver":"0_0","form_factor":"PHONE+TABLET","implementer":"WIDEVINE","fused":true}
    02-29 14:46:14.465 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:14.465 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.452 I [cdm_usage_table.cpp(203):RestoreTable] Found usage table to restore: entry_count = 0
    02-29 14:46:16.462 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.473 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.474 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.474 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.477 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.478 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.479 I [cdm_engine.cpp(216):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid55
    02-29 14:46:16.479 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1032):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid55
    02-29 14:46:16.482 I [cdm_engine.cpp(937):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid55
    02-29 14:46:16.483 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2218):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid55, playback_id = mtHZnGZ3Qp4ZFN3W
    02-29 14:46:16.499 I [cdm_engine.cpp(303):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid55, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
    02-29 14:46:16.499 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.499 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.558 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1043):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
    02-29 14:46:16.771 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.772 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.772 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.773 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.774 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.775 I [cdm_engine.cpp(216):OpenSession] New session: session_id = sid56
    02-29 14:46:16.775 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1032):QueryOemCryptoSessionId] session_id = sid56
    02-29 14:46:16.776 I [cdm_engine.cpp(937):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid56
    02-29 14:46:16.777 I [cdm_engine.cpp(2218):SetPlaybackId] session_id = sid56, playback_id = mtHZnGZ3Qp4ZFN3W
    02-29 14:46:16.779 I [cdm_engine.cpp(303):GenerateKeyRequest] session_id = sid56, key_set_id = <empty>, license_type = Streaming
    02-29 14:46:16.779 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.779 I [file_utils.cpp(38):Exists] stat failed: ENOENT
    02-29 14:46:16.824 I [cdm_engine.cpp(1043):IsSecurityLevelSupported] level = L1
    02-29 14:46:16.826 I [cdm_engine.cpp(937):QuerySessionStatus] session_id = sid56
  ============================== End of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onError(DefaultDrmSession.java:544)
      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onKeysError(DefaultDrmSession.java:534)
      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onKeyResponse(DefaultDrmSession.java:519)
      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.access$100(DefaultDrmSession.java:61)
      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession$ResponseHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSession.java:584)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
      ... 3 more
```

We need exoplayer to play the content on android version 13 devices

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue with Android 14 on Bitmovin offline playback (which uses Exoplayer). Error shows: `ERROR_DRM_UNKNOWN cdm err: 1, oem err: 29, ctx: 23`.

Can you confirm you're not getting this on Android 14?